# scroll a div between 2 fixed DIVs, Position: does not work for me

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to scroll content between two fixed DIVs (Header and Footer).
The scrollable area has a fixed (sub)header and variable text which is what I need to scroll.
I've got some of the way but am now stuck.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/template.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="toprightimage"><img src="images/topimage.png" alt="Nutwith Cote" title="Nutwith Cote" /></div>
    <img id="topbordertext" img="" src="images/HPGtitle.png" alt="Panaramic view" title="HPG Name" />
</div><!-- end of id="header" -->
</div><!-- end of id="header-wrapper" -->

<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="tabline">
        <a href="#" class="Button">Home</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">About Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Current Work</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Achievements</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Events</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Publications</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">The Project</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Methodology</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Location map</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="#" class="Button">Links</a>
    </div><!-- end of id="tabline" -->
        <div id="content">
            First line of text: (extracted from http://lipsum.com/)
            <!--#config errmsg="" --> <!--#include virtual="ZZ_BigLoremIpsum.txt" -->
            Last line of text:
            </div><!-- end of id="content" -->

    </div><!-- end of div id="content-wrapper -->


    <div id="footer-wrapper"> 
        <!--#config errmsg="" --> <!--#include virtual="ZZ_dataserver.footer" -->
    </div><!-- end of div id="footer-wrapper" -->

</body>
```

and the CSS looks like this:

```
*   {
    margin:0;}
body {
    min-width:640px;}
/* Absolute positioned header for all browsers*/
#header-wrapper {
    position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100px;}
/* Reset header position to fixed for real browsers such as Firefox*/
body>#header-wrapper {
    position:fixed;}
#header {
    height:100px;margin:0 auto;width:100%;position:fixed;}
#content {
    padding-top:3px;}
#content-wrapper {
    padding: 0;padding-top:130px;
    padding-bottom:30px;position: static;}
body{
    background-color:#66FFFF;
    background-image:url('/images  /gradient3.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;margin-left: 5px;}
#footer-wrapper {
    position:absolute;bottom:0;left:0;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;height:30px;
    border-top-style: solid;border-top-color: black;
    border-top-width: 2px;width:100%;}
body>#footer-wrapper {
    position:fixed;}
#tabline{
    position:fixed;background-color:#F0F8FF;
    top:100px;width:100%;padding-top:5px;
    overflow: auto;border-style: solid;border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #f9f9f9;} 
#toprightimage {
    position:fixed;}
#topbordertext {
    bottom: 0;left: 0;margin: auto;position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;}
```

The only way I can get the variable text to be seen and to scroll is by padding the DIV (content-wrapper) so that the txt starts under the line of tabs.
The main issue I see is when the page is narrowed down to the point the tab line folds, the folded tab obscures the initial lines of text.

Using Firebug I can see that the DIV seems to be anchored from the top of the screen (viewport?) whereas I would have expected it to start below the preceeding DIV (tabline).
That is what I read when I look up position in e.g http://www.w3schools.com.

Can somebody explain what I've got wrong and how to correct it please?

You can view the page in question by this url: 
[hpg-nidderdale.co.uk/template.shtml](http://hpg-nidderdale.co.uk/template.shtml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about looking at using a responsive design using

> `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { }`

or whatever the width is that causes the menu to cover the subtitle and changing the body `padding-top` or `margin-top` to give the right amount of pixels so that the subtitle displays.

Scroll through this tutorial (http://www.entheosweb.com/website_design/responsive_web_design.asp) and you can see how to implement it and what some other things you can do with it are.

**EDIT:**

Try adding this to your css sheet

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 810px) {
    #content-wrapper {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 434px) {
    #content-wrapper {
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting link. I've taken a look but as it stands it fails to address my requirement to scroll just the content text. It does offer a good start for when I begin to look at making web pages accessible across other devices.

Comment: Well the problem though, is,that after you resize the screen or use a smaller screen than a desktop you can't see the first line of text, right?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a solution, let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, that works fine, thank you. Can I ask if you would explain how you calculated the 2 max-width dimensions?

Comment: Excellent! I opened the link you put in your question and using the developer tools in firefox I was able to edit the css and I used trial and error until the pixels were exactly where you needed them to be.

Comment: If this solved your question, would you mind marking it as the answer?

Comment: Marked as answer - grateful thanks. BTW after asking how you arrived at the pixel values for the media query I found one way of getting them.  I included the JS code as found on: http://www.scriptingmaster.com/scripts/JavaScript/browser-functions/display-browser-information.asp (using viewport-width not screen-width) and set an onclick button to call it when the display "folded".  It's a bit rough and ready but gives a quick result. (Just in case it helps somebody).

Answer (score 0):

I assume something is wrong with the *relative* *positioning* here.
To make the inner "containers" flow and position as desired, relative to the body.

use for the body

```
<body style="position:relative;"/>
```

and for other elements

```
<div style="position:absolute;"/>
```

Comment: tried that. All it does is to lose the tabs and the footer and scrolls the entire page.